# How can I remove duplicates from an MPMediaQuery? The effort below has a fatal error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, duplicates, mpmediaquery

I am making a Music Player app.  MPMediaQuery returns duplicates.  For example, when I get the list of songs from a certain album (10 songs are on the actually CD), 1 song shows up twice.  I don't know why.  Maybe I had sampled my old CD for the 1 song and then at some point later, I sampled the whole CD.  I don't know.  Anyway, my app and Apple's music app lists the song twice, so when I go to play the album, I hear that song twice.  I'd like to eliminate this.  By the way, as you might expect, there are 11 different PersistentIDs (one is out of sequence).

I've spend a bunch of time changing the code and searching stack overflow.

```
// Filter the Albums by the Artist (PASSED in from the previous View Controller)

let predicateByArtist = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: selectedArtist, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtist)
// Filter the Songs by the AlbumTitle (PASSED in from the previous View Controller)
let predicateByAlbumTitle = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: selectedAlbumTitle, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle)
// Query the songs
qrySongs = MPMediaQuery.songs()
qrySongs.addFilterPredicate(predicateByArtist)
qrySongs.addFilterPredicate(predicateByAlbumTitle)

//********** June 19, 2019 additional effort...
// At this point, qrySongs has 11 songs (note: the album City to City really only has 10 songs
// In an effort to learn Xcode/Swift, I thought would if I made a new array of MPMediaItems that only had the list of unique song titles (I'm trying to skip the one duplicate).  Then I could use this list: qrySongsUnique when I assign titles to the TableView.  The theory being that the MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer is really just playing a PersistentID.
// Maybe this idea will not work, maybe it will (but should only be used with small arrays like albums) ... but I'm confused as to why I'm getting a fatal error...

let count = qrySongs.items?.count
print(count!)  // Optional(11)
var i: Int = 0
var lastRowItemTitle: String = ""
var qrySongsUnique: [MPMediaItem] = [MPMediaItem]()

if count ?? 0 > 0 {
    while i < count ?? 0 {
        print(i)  // 0
        let currentRowItemTitle = qrySongs.items![i].title
        print(currentRowItemTitle!)  // Optional("The Ark")
        if currentRowItemTitle != lastRowItemTitle {
            print(qrySongs.items![i]) // <MPConcreteMediaItem: 0x280f4da10> 6027817404062467305
            qrySongsUnique[i] = qrySongs.items![i]  // Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
            lastRowItemTitle = currentRowItemTitle ?? "skipped"
        }
        i = i + 1
    }
}
//**********
```

A list of unique song titles

Comment: The "duplicate" song is: Baker Street.  I own the actual vinyl album and CD.  There are 10 songs.  Baker Street is the second song and it appears only once.  While I understand that I have 2 different persistentIDs, each representing the "same" musical song, I only want one of them to appear in my TableView.  That way if you start playing the whole album/cd, you will 10 songs, you will hear Baker Street second and you will only hear it once.  That's why I came up with the above idea (yesterday) to try to remove the "second version".  I don't understand why an index of 0 is out of range (above)

Comment: I found the bug in the code above. qrySongsUnique[I] is skipping the next open position.  I fixed it.  The idea worked.  But I'll also have to create an array of "skipped" indexes and use it in TableView cellForRowAt.  As much as I think it will work, I'm putting this part of it on hold, so that I can work on more important feature.  For the moment, I deleted the extra song in iTunes and resynced (easy way out).  Still, an album should be enjoyed the way the artist intended (yes, I am old school).